# There is a good way to declare BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I saw this code for scanning WIFI network on this site: http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks.

I implemented the code in the website. It works fine, but when I put the `BroadcastReceiver` in an external class and call it in my activity, my log but always giving nullpointer.

I'm calling the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onCreate` method called by `wifiReceiver.getWifiManager.startScan()`, so basically it should start the `onReceive` method from my receiver. Maybe I am wrong. Then, I call `wifiReceiver.getListResult`, iterate it to output.

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Is there a right way to do it? I searched over the web and I saw people doing it in different ways, like:

- nested inside a class
- this way

```
BroacastReceiver  receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        do something
    }
};
```

- or create a external class and call it

My simple test to see if it work this is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    private WifiManager mainWifi;
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
    }

    public List<ScanResult> getListResult(){
       return wifiList;
    }

    public WifiManager getWifiManager(){
       return mainWifi;
    }
}
```

In the manifest file, I already declared my receiver and gave permissions:

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
    </intent-filter>        
</receiver>
```

And the instantiation of my activity:

```
WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to instantiate a class, including all of the ones you mention. Which one you choose depends on what you're trying to accomplish, so there's no "best" option. I try to avoid anonymous classes (your second proposal), because they're not as obvious as other options.

The method BroadcastReceiver.onReceive is invoked by the system when your app receives a broadcast Intent for which your receiver is registered.

Once onReceive() finishes, the BroadcastReceiver is destroyed. You can't count on it saving any of its state. The full receiver lifecycle is described in the reference documentation for BroadcastReceiver.

As a result, once onReceive finishes, wifiList no longer exists.

Use a broadcast receiver to *receive* messages and decide what to do. Don't put processing in a broadcast receiver; instead, call methods. This means that a good option for defining the broadcast receiver is to make it an inner class of an Activity (or Fragment), which allows the receiver to call methods in the Activity or Fragment.

Comment: Thank you i was looking for that kind of explanation i don't know why i got a negative vote without having any explanation but your reponse make me happy.